# Purpose of OG/Facebook meta property="fb:smart_publish:robots"

Tags: facebook, meta-tags, meta

On this [page](https://www.buzzfeed.com/claudiakoerner/another-police-body-camera-video-allegedly-shows-officers?utm_term=.kkGY7LLxJ#.pvgdr00lp), I can find this meta:

```
<meta property="fb:smart_publish:robots" content="noauto">
```

I failed to find what was the meaning or purpose of this meta anywhere on the web.

Comment: Well I’d guess that probably has to do with https://www.facebook.com/facebookmedia/get-started/smart-publishing

Comment: thanks, I think you're right